# Using Consul KV store for inventory details, possible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

Is it possible to use KV information from Consul to populate the inventory during runtime?

I would like to pull KV information from Consul when running ansible-playbooks to populate the inventory with the host and role assignment.
Since consul_kv is a lookup plugin I'm assuming it doesn't work for inventory (at least it doesn't when I briefly tested it :) ).

The basic idea is to use --extra-vars and supply the hostname and from there pull the information from Consul.

Just need to know if it's possible using the built-in functions (if so which plugins would be appropriate if needed) or if some sort of workaround is the only way. E.g. create the inventory/role files via a script before running the playbook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still think the dynamic inventory is the *most correct* answer to your question, but if I strictly answer just the one you asked, then you will want to use [`add_host:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/modules/add_host_module.html#add-host-module) to do what you described:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - add_host:
      name: '{{ item }}'
      groups:
      - consul_hosts
    with_consul_kv:
    - the/awesome/key/here/{{ and_jinja2_vars }}/or-whatever

- hosts: consul_hosts
  tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: hello from {{ansible_host}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is to use the [dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html) mechanism, and from there you can use any programming language you'd like, including `bash` and invoking the consul CLI to run whatever queries you want. So long as the output is the JSON that ansible is expecting, that contract is well-defined.

However, I was actually curious how hard it would be to reach into ansible and take advantage of the existing `consul_kv` since it is already implemented, will already be available wherever you have ansible, you seem to want to use it, and so forth.

And the answer appears to be "not very hard" (here I'm using the [`dig`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/plugins/lookup/dig.html) lookup since I don't have `consul` nor `python-consul` available to test, but `dig` will do for our purposes):

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
# coding=utf-8
import json
import sys
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.plugins.loader import lookup_loader
dl = DataLoader()
dig_lu = lookup_loader.get("dig", loader=dl)
ips = dig_lu.run(["stackoverflow.com."], variables={}) # type: List[str]
hv = {
    'host{}'.format(idx): {"ansible_host": n}
    for idx, n in enumerate(ips)
}
results = {
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": hv,
    },
    "all": {
        "hosts": list(hv.keys()),
    },
}
json.dump(results, sys.stdout)
```

If you place that in a file, `my_lookup.py`, make it executable with `chmod 755 my_lookup.py`, check its output using `ansible-inventory -i ./my_lookup.py --list` to ensure you and ansible are on the same page, then you can use it as an inventory source `ansible -i ./my_lookup.py -m setup all` and you're off to the races

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I mark the first one as the answer since it was the first but I'll look into both and see which one I'll go for.